# How to find the proportion of flips land heads

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Coin 1 comes up heads with probability 0.6 and coin 2 with probability 0.5. A coin is continually flipped until it comes up tails, at which time that coin is put aside and we start flipping the other one. What proportion of flips land heads?

I can consider a Markov Chain with states 1,2 which is the coin to be flipped at time n. Then I can get the transition matrix \begin{bmatrix}0.6&0.4\\ 0.5&0.5\end{bmatrix} Then we can find the long-run proportion $\pi_1=5/9$ and $\pi_2=4/9$. What is the proportion of flips land head? I use $P=0.6\pi_1+0.5\pi_2=5/9$, is it correct? I am confused about what is the meaning of long-run proportion?

Comment: The approach sounds right to me.  I haven't checked the numerical calculations.  One way of looking at the long run proportion: Let $x_n=1$ if the chain in state $1$ at time $n$ and $0$ otherwise.  Then $\pi_1 = \lim_{k\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{n=1}^kx_n$

Comment: Thanks. I think for this one maybe we should consider the distribution of flip coin.

Comment: I'm not sure how that differs from what I said. I've checked, and $\pi_1=\frac59$ is correct, and that is the long-run proportion of  heads.